# UPDATE con Subquery PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, oracle, subconsultas

buenas tardes, tengo el siguiente inconveniente con unas consultas en SQL, estoy manejando el gestor de base de datos postgreSQL, mi base de datos cuenta con 6 tablas, de las cuales 2 son tabla pivote, las tablas tienen el siguiente nombre:

- Vendedor
- Cliente
- Producto
- Salario
- Vendedor_Producto
- Cliente_Producto

Como se puede observar por el nombre de dichas tablas se darán una idea de cual es el tipo de relación que hay entre ellas, a continuación describo la relación de cada una de estas tablas.

La empresa de nombre "Soy Sano" tiene en sus filas de trabajadores a personas que desempeñan el rol de Agente de ventas, que vienen siendo los vendedores, estos a su vez atienden vía telefonica a usuarios, es decir, posibles clientes los cuales se les ofrece una serie de productos, los productos que se venden son de tipo informático, monitores, computadoras, teclados, fuentes de energía entre otros, la relación de estas tablas a como las he designado es la siguiente:

- Un vendedor puede atender a varios clientes.
- Un cliente es atendido por un único vendedor.

La tabla que posee la relación más fuerte se queda con el campo identificador (id) de la tabla que contiene la relación más devil, pero esta pasa a ser una clave foranea, (al menos así lo he aprendido).

La siguiente relación esta entre las tablas "vendedor" y "producto".

- Un vendedor puede ofrecer varios productos.
- Un producto puede ser ofrecido por varios vendedores.

Al ser una relación del tipo "muchos a muchos" entre ambas entidades (tablas), se crea una tabla intermedia, a la cual la conozco como tabla pivote, y esta tabla únicamente almacena la información de los campos identificadores (id) de ambas tablas, esta tabla intermedia la he nombrado como: "Vendedor_Producto".

La siguiente relación la encontramos con las siguientes tablas, "vendedor" y "salario", la relación entre ambas es la siguiente.

- Un vendedor percibe un salario.
- Un salario puede estar presente en varios vendedores.

En esta relación la tabla fuerte es "vendedor", quien se queda con la columna identificador (id) de la tabla salario.

La última relación se encuentra entre las tablas "cliente" y "producto", la relación entre ambas es la siguiente.

- Un cliente puede adquirir varios productos.
- Un producto puede ser adquirido por varios cliente.

Una vez más se presenta la relación "muchos a muchos", por lo cual surge la siguiente tabla pivote llamada: "Cliente_Producto".

Teniendo esta descripción de como están relacionadas estas tablas comparto el código para que pueda ser más entendible.

```
--Creamos la tabla producto.
CREATE TABLE producto(
   matricula_producto INT NOT NULL,
   nombre_producto VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
   precio FLOAT,
   CONSTRAINT llave_principal_producto PRIMARY KEY(matricula_producto),
   CONSTRAINT llave_unica_producto UNIQUE(nombre_producto)
 );
 --Creamos la tabla salario.
CREATE TABLE salario(
   matricula_salario INT NOT NULL,
   categoria VARCHAR(50),
   monto FLOAT,
   CONSTRAINT llave_principal_salario PRIMARY KEY(matricula_salario),
   CONSTRAINT llave_unica_salario UNIQUE(categoria)
);

--Creamos la tabla vendedor.
CREATE TABLE vendedor(
   matricula_vendedor INT NOT NULL,
   nombre_vendedor VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
   apellido_vendedor VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
   sexo VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   salario_matricula INT NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT llave_unica_vendedor UNIQUE(nombre_vendedor,apellido_vendedor),
   CONSTRAINT llave_principal_vendedor PRIMARY KEY(matricula_vendedor),
   CONSTRAINT llave_extranjera_vendedor FOREIGN KEY(salario_matricula) REFERENCES salario(matricula_salario)
       ON UPDATE RESTRICT
       ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

--Creamos la tabla cliente.
CREATE TABLE cliente(
   matricula_cliente INT NOT NULL,
   nombre_cliente VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
   apellido_cliente VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
   vendedor_matricula INT NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT llave_unica_cliente UNIQUE(nombre_cliente,apellido_cliente),
   CONSTRAINT llave_principal_cliente PRIMARY KEY(matricula_cliente),
   CONSTRAINT llave_extranjera_cliente FOREIGN KEY(vendedor_matricula) REFERENCES vendedor(matricula_vendedor)
       ON UPDATE RESTRICT
       ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

--Tabla pivote.
--Viene de la relación cliente y producto.
CREATE TABLE cliente_producto(
   cliente_matricula INT NOT NULL,
   producto_matricula INT NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT llave_extranjera_1_clienteProducto FOREIGN KEY(cliente_matricula) REFERENCES cliente(matricula_cliente),
   CONSTRAINT llave_extranjera_2_clienteProducto FOREIGN KEY(producto_matricula) REFERENCES producto(matricula_producto)
       ON UPDATE RESTRICT
       ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

--Tabla pivote.
--Viene de la relación vendedor y producto.
CREATE TABLE vendedor_producto(
   vendedor_matricula_producto INT NOT NULL,
   producto_matricula_producto INT NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT llave_extranjera_1_vendedorProducto FOREIGN KEY(vendedor_matricula_producto) REFERENCES vendedor(matricula_vendedor),
   CONSTRAINT llave_extranjera_2_vendedorProducto FOREIGN KEY(producto_matricula_producto) REFERENCES producto(matricula_producto)
       ON UPDATE RESTRICT
       ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

--Insertamos información a nuestras tablas.
INSERT INTO producto VALUES
(1,'CPU',14500.55),
(2,'Teclado',320.50),
(3,'Mouse',173.50),
(4,'Monitor',6500.50);

INSERT INTO salario VALUES
(1,'A',5600.55),
(2,'B',4800.25),
(3,'C',3500.60);

INSERT INTO vendedor VALUES
(1,'Maricamen','Castro','Femenino',3),(2,'Maricela','Perez','Femenino',3),
(3,'Monica','Prado','Femenino',2),(4,'Mario','Briseño','Masculino',1),
(5,'Mauricio','Aguirre','Masculino',2),(6,'Marco','Huerta','Masculino',2),
(7,'Luis','Herrera','Masculino',3),(8,'Angel','Hernandez','Masculino',3),
(9,'Armando','Zuñiga','Masculino',1),(10,'Heriberto','Zarate','Masculino',2);

INSERT INTO cliente VALUES
(1,'Edwin','Zapata',2),(2,'Edgar','Cancino',3),(3,'Alison','Cordova',4),
(4,'Andrea','Cisneros',5),(5,'Gabriela','Fuentes',1),(6,'Carolina','Prado',8),
(7,'Alejandra','Parada',6),(8,'Ana','Rueda',7),(9,'Maria','Rico',10),
(10,'Rebeca','Huerta',9),(11,'Ricardo','Morgado',3),(12,'Rogelio','Novoa',3),
(13,'Roberto','Rentería',3),(14,'Pablo','Montelogon',1),(15,'Damian','Martínez',4),
(16,'Felipe','Medellin',4),(17,'Donovan','Percastegui',5),(18,'Doris','Perez',6),
(19,'Doribel','Luna',7),(20,'Ariana','Cervantes',8);

INSERT INTO cliente_producto VALUES
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(2,4),(1,1),(4,2),
(5,3),(6,4),(6,1),(8,2),(9,3),(9,4),(11,1),(10,2),(12,3),(13,4),(14,1),
(15,2),(7,3),(7,4),(16,1),(16,2),(17,3),(19,4),(18,1),(20,2),(1,3),
(3,4),(2,1),(2,2),(1,3),(7,4),(6,1),(3,2),(5,3),(4,4);

INSERT INTO vendedor_producto 
VALUES
(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,1),(6,2),(7,3),(8,4),(9,1),(10,2),
(1,3),(2,4),(3,1),(4,2),(5,3),(6,4),(7,1),(8,2),(9,3),(10,4),
(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,1),(6,2),(7,3),(8,4),(9,1),(10,2),
(1,3),(2,4),(3,1),(4,2),(5,3),(6,4),(7,1),(8,2),(9,3),(10,4);
```

Mi duda es la siguiente, quiero actualizar el salario de los vendedores, unicamente para aquellas personas que hayan vendido más de 6 productos en adelante, para poder realizar esto, lo que hice fue lo siguiente.

Primero calcule quienes eran los clientes que mas ventas hayan realizado, con la siguiente condición, mostrar ventas superior a 6 artículos, para esto utilice la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT      matricula_vendedor,
            monto
FROM        vendedor
INNER JOIN  cliente 
 ON         matricula_vendedor=vendedor_matricula
INNER JOIN  cliente_producto
 ON         matricula_cliente=cliente_matricula
INNER JOIN  producto
 ON         matricula_producto=producto_matricula
INNER JOIN  salario
 ON         salario_matricula=matricula_salario
GROUP BY        matricula_vendedor,
            monto
HAVING      COUNT(matricula_vendedor)>6
ORDER BY    matricula_vendedor DESC;
```

Como resultado me arroja que los vendedores Marco con id 4 y Heriberto con id 3 son los mejores vendedores, ya que han logrado vender más productos, el paso importante que no me ha sido posible solucionar es el siguiente.

Realizar un incremento en el salario de los vendedores que tengan la mejor cantidad de ventas, para este paso utilice lo siguiente, crear un UPDATE uniéndolo con una subconsulta para poder realizar el incremento salarial, pero los resultados no son los esperados, a continuación la consulta.

```
UPDATE  salario
SET     monto=(monto*150)
WHERE   matricula_salario IN(
                            SELECT      matricula_vendedor
                            FROM        vendedor
                            INNER JOIN  cliente 
                                ON      matricula_vendedor=vendedor_matricula
                            INNER JOIN  cliente_producto
                                ON      matricula_cliente=cliente_matricula
                            INNER JOIN  producto
                                ON      matricula_producto=producto_matricula
                            INNER JOIN  salario
                                ON      salario_matricula=matricula_salario
                            GROUP BY    matricula_vendedor
                            HAVING      COUNT(matricula_vendedor)>6
                        );
```

Aplica la operación, pero no lo ejecuta con los vendedores correctos, el incremento lo realiza con los vendedores que han obtenido ventas bajas, como por ejemplo:

Ángel con id 7, Luis con id 8, Maricela con id 9 y Maricarmen con id 10.

He intentando otras maneras pero me da los mismos resultados, ¿podrían orientarme por favor?, ¿Qué temas debo repasar o investigar para mejorar en el tema de subconsultas?, de antemano envío un cordial saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He realizado la siguiente modificación del ejercicio anterior, y me a quedado de la siguiente manera, tengo tres tablas principales, "vendedor", "cliente" y "producto", estas tablas no tienen relación directa entre si, todas ellas se unen mediante una tabla intermedia, o conocida como la tabla pivote, en esta tabla se encuentran los "id" de cada una de las tablas anteriores, no las llame id como tal, les coloque el nombre de "matricula", en la tabla pivote se encuentra la relación entre las tres tablas anteriores, es decir, en una única tabla se conoce quien es el vendedor, a que clientes ha atendido dicho vendedor y que producto les vendió.

Comparto el código para que se pueda entender un poco mejor.

Esta es la estructura lógica de las tablas incluida la tabla pivote.

```
CREATE TABLE producto(
   matricula_producto INT NOT NULL,
   descripcion VARCHAR(150),
   precio FLOAT,
   CONSTRAINT llave_principal_producto PRIMARY KEY(matricula_producto)
);

CREATE TABLE cliente(
   matricula_cliente INT NOT NULL,
   nombre_cliente VARCHAR(150),
   apellido_cliente VARCHAR(150),
   CONSTRAINT llave_principal_cliente PRIMARY KEY(matricula_cliente)
);

CREATE TABLE vendedor(
   matricula_vendedor INT NOT NULL,
   nombre_vendedor VARCHAR(150),
   apellido_vendedor VARCHAR(150),
   salario FLOAT,
   CONSTRAINT llave_principal_vendedor PRIMARY KEY(matricula_vendedor)
);

CREATE TABLE vendedor_cliente_producto(
   vendedor_matricula INT NOT NULL,
   cliente_matricula INT NOT NULL,
   producto_matricula INT NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT llave_extranjera_vendedor FOREIGN KEY(vendedor_matricula) REFERENCES vendedor(matricula_vendedor)
       ON UPDATE RESTRICT
       ON DELETE RESTRICT,
   CONSTRAINT llave_extranjera_cliente FOREIGN KEY(cliente_matricula) REFERENCES cliente(matricula_cliente)
       ON UPDATE RESTRICT
       ON DELETE RESTRICT,
   CONSTRAINT llave_extranjera_producto FOREIGN KEY(producto_matricula) REFERENCES producto(matricula_producto)
       ON UPDATE RESTRICT
       ON DELETE RESTRICT 
);
```

Después agregamos información a cada una de las tablas anteriormente creadas.

```
--Insertamos registros en producto
INSERT INTO producto 
VALUES
(1,'CPU',14325.50),(2,'Monitor',6750.30),
(3,'Teclado',678.25),(4,'Mouse',328.25),
(5,'Fuente de energía',6825.50);

--Insertamos registros en cliente
INSERT INTO cliente 
VALUES
(1,'Jorge','Spindola'),(2,'Ricardo','Araujo'),(3,'Marcos','Medina'), 
(4,'Edwin','Anaya'),(5,'Roberto','Novoa'),
(6,'Fernanda','Cisneros'),(7,'Patricia','Morales'),(8,'Ana','Percastegui'), 
(9,'Sofia','Velasco'),(10,'Sandra','Heredia'),
(11,'Edgar','Rodriguez'),(12,'Esteban','Villar'),(13,'Guadalupe','Moreno'), 
(14,'Nicolas','Cordova'),(15,'Maricela','Aguilar'),
(16,'Alison','Martínez'),(17,'Alejandra','Rosas'),(18,'Eshter','Moran'), 
(19,'Nohemi','Monzon'),(20,'Esther','Díaz'),
(21,'Andrea','Chimal'),(22,'Jessica','Benitez'),(23,'Guillermo','Mejia'), 
(24,'Osvaldo','Hipolito'),(25,'Ariana','Briseño');

--Insertamos registros en vendedor
INSERT INTO vendedor 
VALUES
(1,'Cristian','Huerta',4320.99),(2,'Luis','Fonseca',3285.25), 
(3,'Lizbeth','Urrutia',3055.25),(4,'Mario','Morgado',3855.25), 
(5,'Lucia','Teran',4125.75),
(6,'Leonardo','Moran',3929.50),(7,'Gerardo','Palacio',4025.25);

--Insertamos datos en la tabla pivote
INSERT INTO vendedor_cliente_producto 
VALUES
(1,23,4),(1,1,1),(1,2,2),(1,3,3),(1,4,4),
(1,5,5),(1,6,1),(1,7,2),(1,8,3),(1,9,4),
(1,10,5),(1,11,1),(1,12,2),(1,13,3),(1,14,4),
(1,15,5),(1,16,1),(1,17,2),(1,18,3),(1,19,4),
(1,20,5),(1,21,1),(1,22,2),(1,23,3),(1,24,4),
(1,25,5),(1,1,1),(1,2,2),(1,3,3),(1,4,4),
(2,5,5),(2,6,1),(2,7,2),(2,8,3),(2,9,4),
(2,10,5),(2,11,1),(2,12,2),(2,13,3),(2,14,4),
(2,15,5),(2,16,1),(2,17,2),(2,18,3),(2,19,4),
(3,20,5),(3,21,1),(3,22,2),(3,23,3),(3,24,4),
(3,25,5),(3,1,1),(3,2,2),(3,3,3),(3,4,4),
(3,5,5),(3,6,1),(3,7,2),(3,8,3),(3,9,4),
(1,10,5),(1,11,1),(1,12,2),(1,13,3),(1,14,4),
(1,15,5),(1,16,1),(1,17,2),(1,18,3),(1,19,4),
(1,20,5),(1,21,1),(1,22,2),(1,23,3),(1,24,4),
(4,25,5),(4,1,1),(4,2,2),(4,3,3),(4,4,4),
(4,5,5),(4,6,1),(4,7,2),(4,8,3),(4,9,4),
(4,10,5),(4,11,1),(4,12,2),(4,13,3),(4,14,4),
(4,15,5),(4,16,1),(4,17,2),(4,18,3),(4,19,4),
(5,20,5),(5,21,1),(5,22,2),(5,23,3),(5,24,4),
(5,25,5),(5,1,1),(5,2,2),(5,3,3),(5,4,4),
(5,5,5),(5,6,1),(5,7,2),(5,8,3),(5,9,4),
(6,10,5),(6,11,1),(6,12,2),(6,13,3),(6,14,4),
(6,15,5),(6,16,1),(6,17,2),(6,18,3),(6,19,4),
(6,20,5),(6,21,1),(6,22,2),(6,23,3),(6,24,4),
(6,25,5),(6,1,1),(6,2,2),(6,3,3),(6,4,4),
(6,5,5),(6,6,1),(6,7,2),(6,8,3),(6,9,4),
(1,10,5),(1,11,1),(1,12,2),(1,13,3),(1,14,4),
(1,15,5),(1,16,1),(1,17,2),(1,18,3),(1,19,4),
(1,20,5),(1,21,1),(1,22,2),(1,23,3),(1,24,4),
(1,25,5),(1,1,1),(1,2,2),(1,3,3),(1,4,4),
(1,5,5),(1,6,1),(1,7,2),(1,8,3),(1,9,4),
(2,10,5),(2,11,1),(2,12,2),(2,13,3),(2,14,4),
(2,15,5),(2,16,1),(2,17,2),(2,18,3),(2,19,4),
(2,20,5),(2,21,1),(2,22,2),(2,23,3),(2,24,4),
(7,25,5),(7,1,1),(7,2,2),(7,3,3),(7,4,4),
(7,5,5),(7,6,1),(7,7,2),(7,8,3),(7,9,4),
(7,10,5),(7,11,1),(7,12,2),(7,13,3),(7,14,4),
(7,15,5),(7,16,1),(7,17,2),(7,18,3),(7,19,4),
(7,20,5),(7,21,1),(7,22,2),(7,23,3),(7,24,4),
(3,25,5),(3,1,1),(3,2,2),(3,3,3),(3,4,4),
(3,5,5),(3,6,1),(3,7,2),(3,8,3),(3,9,4),
(5,10,5),(5,11,1),(5,12,2),(5,13,3),(5,14,4),
(6,15,5),(6,16,1),(6,17,2),(6,18,3),(6,19,4),
(1,20,5),(2,21,1),(3,22,2),(4,23,3),(7,24,4);
```

Por último, realizo la consulta de actualizar la tabla vendedor con la condición que solo se aplique un aumento salarial a aquellos vendedores que superen la cantidad de 50 artículos vendidos, para ello utilizo una subquery dentro de la actualización para saber que vendedor ha ofrecido o vendido más artículos, la consulta completa es la siguiente:

```
UPDATE  vendedor 
SET     salario=(salario*13)
WHERE   matricula_vendedor 
   IN  (
         SELECT      matricula_vendedor
         FROM        vendedor AS agente_venta
         INNER JOIN  (
                        SELECT      vendedor_matricula 
                        FROM        vendedor_cliente_producto
                        GROUP BY    vendedor_matricula 
                        HAVING      COUNT(vendedor_matricula)>50
                      ) AS mejor_vendedor
                ON agente_venta.matricula_vendedor=mejor_vendedor.vendedor_matricula
  );
```

Cambiando el diseño de la base de datos he podido solucionar el problema que se me presentaba con anterioridad, mi diseño de dicha base es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias David JP por los puntos de vista, estudiare más para mejorar en este tema de las bases de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Además de partir de una base de datos con un diseño mejorable, pues no puedes tener las ventas en dos tablas, clientes y vendedores, sino un única llamada ventas en las que ya podrías vincular a productos, clientes y vendedores; estás agrupando por el campo que no es. Me explico: si quieres saber las ventas de cada vendedor no agrupas por vendedor y monto, sino únicamente por vendedor, y cuentas registros o sumas montos. Y únicamente deberías agrupar en la tabla `vendedor_producto`, y no en la combinación de todas las demás, pues estás multiplicando artificialmente las ventas y obteniendo datos erróneos.

Por otro lado, y con los datos de ejemplo que aportas, todos los vendedores han vendido 4 artículos, ninguno supera los 6. Así que no podrás actualizar el salario de ninguno. Sobre esta cuestión, considera realizar las subidas salariales conforme al dinero que le hagan ganar a la empresa, no según el número de artículos vendidos.

En definitiva, dale una vuelta, organiza bien toda la información y, si tienes más dudas, plantea una nueva pregunta con las dudas que te hayan surgido. Esta pregunta puede estar bien como ejemplo de varios errores que se pueden cometer diseñando bases de datos y explotándolos. Me parece muy didáctica, porque está muy bien planteada, dando la impresión de que todo está correcto, pero oculta errores de concepto difíciles de detectar. Muchas gracias por tu aportación.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para ampliar la respuesta en la dirección que mejor proceda.

Comment: Hola David, buenos días, gracias por la sugerencia, he cambiado totalmente el diseño de la base de datos, como mencionaste en un principio, una tabla en donde se puedan relacionar las otras 3, y así tener un mejor control sobre las queryes a manejar para poder realizar la operación de manera más efectiva, muchas gracias por la aportación, de antemano envío un cordial saludo.